# Responsive jQuery data table not working in tabs and bootstrap modal popup

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have used responsive jquery data table in my project,
i am facing issue in the tabs and popup 
**Issue list**

1. Responsive jquery data table not working in tabs, working only first tab not on second tab(plus symbol not come in the jquery data table).
2. Bootstrap modal window also responsive jquery data table not working(plus symbol not come in the jquery data table).
   Please help me to resolve this issue
   i have tried below code but this is not helped me.

   $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
          $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
          .columns.adjust()
          .responsive.recalc();
      });

   https://jsfiddle.net/97sos7dm/31/

   ```
   <div class="tabpanel-primary">
   <div class="tabpanel-heading">
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs custab" role="tablist">
           <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#invoice" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Invoice</a></li>
           <li role="presentation"><a href="#payee" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Payee</a></li>

       </ul>
       </div>
      <div class="tab-content">
       <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="invoice">

       <div class="row margin-0 datatab">
       </div>
     </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="payee">
   <div class="row margin-0">
   </div>
   ```

Please refer the issue in the above js fiddle link

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
style="overflow-x:auto;"
```

to `<table>` table tag it will become responsive.

Comment: I tried the above also, jquery data table plus symbol not come.I need plus symbol if the table size is large.

Answer (score 0):

Call `Resize` `function` in your `fnInfoCallback` `function`

```
"fnInfoCallback": function (oSettings,
   $(".table").resize() 
},
```

Other Option Call On Change `Event` `Tab` & `Modal`

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on( 'shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
   $(".table").resize()
    } ); 
$('#arPayeeItem').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
 $(".table").resize()
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/97sos7dm/54/